# Google Console Cloud Create credentials OAuth Cliend ID has error

Tags: oauth, google-api, cloud, clientid

[image: 1]

There was an error while loading /apis/credentials/oauthclient?previousPage=%2Fapis%2Fcredentials%3Fproject%3Dmidbooks-8800&project=midbooks-8800. Please try again.

Tracking Number: c7520181810687758

show error when create credentials OAuth cliend id

add some libraries like google+ api and add some scopes but didn't solve